# Check if MySQL column contains characters

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a search page on my website where you can type in the username of a person to bring up their profile although it only works when you type in their full username. I want to check if a rows username column contains a sequence of characters that the user types in so that when they type in: 'Mr' it will bring up the result 'MrDare360' and so on.

This is the code I have at the moment: http://pastebin.com/68dgLZf8

What would be the easiest or best way of doing this?

Comment: You should use `LIKE`. google it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use LIKE.  Contrived example query:

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE name LIKE 'Mr%';
```

The `%` character is a wildcard.  The above example would match a string *starting* with `Mr` (as your question states).  You could also do `%Mr%` to find `Mr` in the middle of a string or `%Mr` to find `Mr` at the end of a string.

[Docs here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$query = $sqli_con->query("SELECT id, username, avatar, first_name, last_name, country, gender, user_level FROM members WHERE username LIKE '%$search_query%'");
```